# How to query/filter by the value of a lightswitch

Tags: craft3, lightswitch

In my news entries, I have a lightswitch field with the handle 'pinned'. I'm trying to query my news section for both pinned and unpinned news entries (true or false essentially), but I can't get consistent results with any of the following:

```
{% set pinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned('1').all() %}
{% set unpinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned('0').all() %}

{% set pinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned('true').all() %}
{% set unpinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned('false').all() %}

{% set pinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned('1').all() %}
{% set unpinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned('not 1').all() %}

{% set pinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').search('pinned:1').all() %} THIS WORKS
{% set unpinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').search('pinned:0').all() %} DOES NOT WORK
{% set unpinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').search('pinned:not 1').all() %} DOES NOT WORK
```

Is there a proper to get the boolean values in Craft 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`true`/`false` are [booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), not [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), so you shouldn't surround them in quotes:

```
{% set pinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned(true).all() %}
{% set unpinnedNews = craft.entries().section('news').pinned(false).all() %}
```

Comment: very good yes programming 101! I promise you this...I set it to (false) then retried, cleared cache, retried, still missing one "false" entry. So I went to that entry, flipped the switch on and off, resaved, tested, bingo. It wasn't until i resaved that i got the correct result. Thank you!

Comment: Huh very interesting. Glad it worked! 

Comment: I've read others have had trouble with switches "sticking". I'll try to find  these.